# Android NumberPicker without blinking cursor

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using the NumberPicker under the Android SDK level 13 inside a fragment. Works fine, but each time the activity is started the cursor is blinking behind the number. How can I get rid of the blinking cursor, I don't know why this widget has the focus.
This is the xml of the NumberPicker:

```
<NumberPicker android:id="@+id/timer_picker_hrs"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I get this solution from somewhere but I don't remember from where. This works good for me,
just do this in your activity.

```
myNumberPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

You can also set this in XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

(Borzh comment)

Comment: You can also set this in XML: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Here is the likely source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854781/disable-soft-keyboard-on-numberpicker

Answer (score 2):

One way of removing the blinking cursor is disabling the soft keyboard for the NumberPicker. (refer to: [Disable soft keyboard on NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854781/disable-soft-keyboard-on-numberpicker) )

Answer (score 0):

**It's gaining focus because of child CustomEditText**

you need to move focus to other view or disable soft input

se my answer for solution:

**[how disable focus on NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854781/disable-soft-keyboard-on-numberpicker/31329186#31329186)**