# Number Picker edit

Tags: android, eclipse

New, made an app with number picker, works ok
But instead of drag, if I tap the number picker, the keyboard pop up and I can type anything in there. How to deactivate this? to make it uneditable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you have the answer: [Disable soft keyboard on NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854781/disable-soft-keyboard-on-numberpicker)

And basically is this:

```
myNumberPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Or put this in the .xml:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```